# perl: get a substring until the last occurence of a character

Tags: string, perl, character

In perl, from this:

```
gi|1339058241|ref|XP_023717639.1|zinc finger and BTB domain-containing protein 18-like [Cryptotermes secundus]
```

if my character is `|`, how can I get the string:

```
gi|1339058241|ref|XP_023717639.1|
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution, that works by removing all characters different than `|` at the end of the given string.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "gi|1339058241|ref|XP_023717639.1|zinc finger and BTB domain-containing protein 18-like [Cryptotermes secundus]";

$str =~ s/[^|]*$//;
print "$str\n;"
```

Explanation :

- `[^|]` is a *character class* : it matches any char but `|` (the "but" is denoted by the `^` character)
- `*` is a quantifier, meaning 0 to N characters
- `$` represents the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why it does not stop at the first '|': so "gi|" ?

Comment: The regex is saying strip all non-pipe characters at the end of the string.  Once it reaches the first pipe (from the right), it "stops"

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, matches are by default "greedy", so you can simply do a match of everything up to the character you are using as your delimiter:

```
$foo="gi|1339058241|ref|XP_023717639.1|zinc finger and BTB domain-containing protein 18-like [Cryptotermes secundus]";
$foo =~ /.*\|/; 
print "$&\n"
```

The `$&` represents the string matched by the last successful pattern match, in this case, everything up to the last `|` character.

Comment: Alternatively, `my ($newfoo) = $foo =~ /(.*\|)/;` if you want the result in a named variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rindex` which is like `index`, only it searches from the right instead of the left side of the string -- pulling the last occurrence of a string instead of the first:

```
substr($str, 0, rindex ($str, '|') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recognize these as NCBI seq header lines so I know they have a fixed number of fields.

Since these are fields/columns, you can split and join:

```
my @rec = split(/\|/, $id);
my $idShort = join("|", @rec[0..3]);
print $idShort, "\n";
```

Or you can use a regex:

```
if ($id =~ /^(gi\|\d+\|\w+\|[\w\_]+\.\d+\|)/) { print "$1\n" } else { die("Unparseable: $id\n") }
```

But I like Hambone's use of rindex.